# How to print checked and unchecked check-boxes in SAS report webout file

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a table of name Proposal in which there is a column name value_cd.
 This column has values of some check boxes that will be checked in my webout report. I want to check all the check-boxes whose relevant value is in this column.

```
table:Proposal 
  value_cd

   New_par
   Rev_par
```

Here is my code

```
data _null_;
 put numberOfObservationes=;
 set work.Proposal nobs=numberOfObservationes;
 file _webout;
    if value_cd eq "New_par" then put '<input type=checkbox disabled checked /> <label>New Parameter</label> <br /> <hr /> ';
          else put '<input type=checkbox disabled /> <label>New Parameter</label> <br /> <hr /> ';
    if value_cd eq "Rev_par" then put '<input type=checkbox disabled checked /> <label>Revised Parameter</label> <br /> <hr /> ';
          else put '<input type=checkbox disabled /> <label>Revised Parameter</label> <br /> <hr /> ';
    if value_cd eq "New_pro" then put '<input type=checkbox disabled checked /> <label>New Process</label> <br /> <hr /> ';
          else put '<input type=checkbox disabled /> <label>New Process</label> <br /> <hr /> ';
run;
```

I want to print a check box only once in my report and it should be checked or unchecked based on the values of column value_cd of my table but when a value is not equal in if condition it runs the else statement and code is printing check boxes till count of value_cd.

How can i print check boxes only once based on the of value_cd.

I want this

```
  checkbox checked New Parameter        *if-statement;
  checkbox checked Revised Parameter    *if-statement;
  checkbox New Process                  *else-statement;
```

upper code is printing output below

```
  checkbox checked New Parameter  *if-statement;
  checkbox Revised Parameter      *else-statement;
  checkbox New Process            *else-statement;
  checkbox New Parameter          *else-statement;
  checkbox checked Revised Parameter   *if-statement;
  checkbox New Process            *else-statement;
```

Comment: Hello. May be you need use SWITCH -CASE function? [example](https://philihp.com/blog/2012/sas-switch-statement/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening row-wise, 6 checkboxes:

```
row-1: logic-1-output logic-2-output logic-3-output
row-2: logic-1-output logic-2-output logic-3-output
```

What is wanted, 3 checkboxes:

```
row-1: track-logic-1-for-true track-logic-2-for-true track-logic-3-for-true
row-2: track-logic-1-for-true track-logic-2-for-true track-logic-3-for-true
last-row: output-based-on-tracked-logics
```

Here is one approach

Track the value_cd states that occur over all the rows, then perform the output.

```
data _null_;
 put numberOfObservationes=;
 set work.Proposal nobs=numberOfObservationes end=last_row;

 array boxes[3] _temporary_; * 1st slot is for New_par, 2nd for Rev_par, etc..;

 * track for true using OR;
 boxes[1] = boxes[1] or (value_cd eq "New_par");
 boxes[2] = boxes[2] or (value_cd eq "Rev_par");
 boxes[3] = boxes[3] or (value_cd eq "New_pro");

 if last_row then do;
    if boxes[1]
      then checked_attribute='checked'; 
      else checked_attribute='';

    put '<input type=checkbox disabled ' checked_attribute '/> <label>New Parameter</label> <br /> <hr /> ';

    if boxes[2]
      then checked_attribute='checked'; 
      else checked_attribute='';

    put '<input type=checkbox disabled ' checked_attribute '/> <label>Revised Parameter</label> <br /> <hr /> ';

    if boxes[3]
      then checked_attribute='checked'; 
      else checked_attribute='';

    put '<input type=checkbox disabled ' checked_attribute '/> <label>New Process</label> <br /> <hr /> ';
  end;
run;
```

NOTE: The above code is essentially pivoting the value_cd data from a column to a single row.

In a DATA Step variable values are normally reset to missing at the top on the implicit loop (in this case when you go from row-1 to row-2). In order to track a condition from row to row a variable should not be reset by the implicit loop.

There are a couple of ways the reset can be avoided:

- Use a `RETAIN` variable
- Use a `_temporary_` array
- Never allow the implicit loop to occur more than once:

  - Use a `SET` within an explicitly coded `do while` or `do until` loop.
- Have all your state information in a single row (i.e. pivoted)